# Tester reads "HOT / GRD. REVERSE"

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Everything was working as usual then NOT.  I used a 3 prong circuit tester in several outlets and got the same reading on all of them. HOT / GRD. REVERSE. how or why would this suddenly happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: You really need to provide more information on what you mean as NOT. Describe the scenario of working up to and through to the NOT situation. Something has changed for you to reach that determination. And that series of events may have next to nothing to do with what you are seeing on this three prong circuit tester that you pulled out of your pocket.

Comment: Please define what kind of indicators are on your tester and what indicators are NOT working as expected. What readings do you get on "good' outlets.

Comment: did you put a voltage tester and check what you have at your receptacle ... check your breaker if you’re not getting 120

Answer (score 3):

For some reason those plug-in receptacle testers show this result when there is an open neutral.

This means the neutral conductor for the circuit is open or compromised somewhere. Most often it is a poor connection at a receptacle where the wires are back-stabbed, or stuck into the "quickwire" holes in the back.

A quick test to do is to plug the tester into each receptacle on the circuit, working or not, and wiggle it. Many times the faulty connection will show as the circuit flickers or comes back on.

The best course is to at the very least move the wires from the quickwire holes to the side screw terminals. The best bet is to replace the receptacle entirely using the side screws.